# Достать данные из object

Tags: c#, массивы

Имеется заполненый массив обьектов:

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 list.Add(new {
 name="das",
 type = "dsds",
 num = i
});
```

Как получить доступ к `name` каждого элемента массива?
P.S. создавать класс или стракты не желательно, т.к. все это нужно только для записи в `JSON`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы используете Anonymous Types. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750078/get-value-from-anonymous-type) пример решения

Comment: Огромное спасибо, dynamic помог мне)

Answer (score 2):

Можно ещё использовать [`var` и список правильного типа](https://ideone.com/TMDXVI):

```
var list =
    Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
              .Select(i => new { name="das", type = "dsds", num = i })
              .ToList();
foreach (var o in list)
    Console.WriteLine("name = {0}, num = {1}", o.name, o.num);
```